# How to solve MySQL deadlock?

Tags: mysql, database-deadlocks

I'm a bit lost with solving MySQL deadlock problem. Here is how I'm getting deadlocks.

Thread #1 runs:

```
    BEGIN;
    SELECT
        sequence_number,
        status
    FROM
        sns_preorders t
    WHERE
        t.program_user_id=1
    ORDER BY
        sequence_number ASC
    FOR UPDATE;
```

Thread #2 runs:

```
    BEGIN;
    SELECT
        sequence_number,
        status
    FROM
        sns_preorders t
    WHERE
        t.program_user_id=2
    ORDER BY
        sequence_number ASC
    FOR UPDATE;
```

In the meanwhile thread #1 runs (and it hangs until the second thread does the same):

```
        INSERT INTO
            sns_preorders
        SET
            program_user_id=1,
            gift_id=1,
            handling_date=now(),
            delivery_date=now(),
            total_price=1000,
            sequence_number=1,
            status=1;
```

Virtually at the same time thread #2 runs:

```
        INSERT INTO
            sns_preorders
        SET
            program_user_id=2,
            gift_id=1,
            handling_date=now(),
            delivery_date=now(),
            total_price=1000,
            sequence_number=1,
            status=1;
```

Thread #2 succeeds with the request, but the thread 1 returns an error `Error Code: 1213. Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction`.

Maybe my understanding of deadlocks is wrong, but I thought that if I lock the rows by a particular `program_user_id` then there should no be a deadlock. What can be a solution here?

*UPDATE*: here is a list of indexes

```
mysql> show index from sns_preorders;
+---------------+------------+---------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table         | Non_unique | Key_name                        | Seq_in_index | Column_name     | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------------+------------+---------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| sns_preorders |          0 | PRIMARY                         |            1 | id              | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| sns_preorders |          0 | program_user_id_sequence_number |            1 | program_user_id | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| sns_preorders |          0 | program_user_id_sequence_number |            2 | sequence_number | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| sns_preorders |          1 | IDX_26A332972C842B41            |            1 | program_user_id | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| sns_preorders |          1 | IDX_26A3329797A95A83            |            1 | gift_id         | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| sns_preorders |          1 | sequence_number                 |            1 | sequence_number | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+---------------+------------+---------------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Comment: `program_user_id` column indexed in `sns_preorders` table?

Comment: okay, we too had similar issue. We fixed the issue by predictive sorting before holding a deadlock. Your case look to be tricky because of different `program_user_id`. Any other connections holding the row locks/table locks on `sns_preorders` table?

Comment: If you execute a query FOR UPDATE the expectation is that you will, err, update those rows. Not insert new ones. If you're not going to update the rows returned by the query, don't use FOR UPDATE.

Comment: @harshavmb no, no other connections; I did the isolation of the problem, so what I gave in the question is a minimal required list of steps to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @EJP ok, maybe you are right, but then, how can I do the trick with insert? The idea is to prevent a second process instance to do the same change while the first one is running.

Comment: @EJP I thought of what you wrote, first of all, you don't know what I'm going to do in the next steps (I didn't show the final part of the transaction). Second: as it is a lock for existing rows (what I really need), then there should no be a deadlock for new rows. So, what you are saying here doesn't help me anyhow. PS. Thanks for -1.

Comment: @EJP it is NOT relevant to the question. If you didn't understand the question, then you should ask me for the clarifications and do not speculate of what I shouldn't do just because you have no other information. I do need `FOR UPDATE`, and that's NOT the point of the question. PS. It's silly to deny that it were you :D